# i am fetching this error banuba video sdk

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMwzs.png)
BanubaSDK error: At /Users/user/buildAgent/work/846da17cdd594915/libs/utils/bnb/utils/scoped_singleton.hpp:63. You are trying to create the second instance of the singleton.: *inst_ptr == nullptr

Loaded with controller, then on navigating the second time it crashes and gives this error

I have tried many times but this error is not getting resolved

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have called `BanubaSdkManager.initialize` twice.

Try to call `BanubaSdkManager.deinitialize` before the second initialization.